# How to structure a user activity table in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm currently having a single activity table that references other tables depending on the type of activity.

```
id | type | user_id | source_id | misc_id | date
```

The type column tells me what kind of activity the user has performed (follow, liked, befriend, status etc.) and the source id contains the table id relative to the type of action.

This is working well for a user activity stream, but the only problem is, I can't figure out what to do about rows that no longer exist in the relative tables?

E.g. a user creates a status and then deletes it, or a user becomes friends with somebody that is later deleted from the database.

If the activity was relative to a single type, then I would be able to add a foreign key constraint, which would remove the row; but as it's relative to different tables, how else could I go about doing this?

Comment: what problems does this cause?

Comment: Because it's returning results that no longer exist in other tables. If I'm running a switch statement on the type of activity and the row doesn't exist I will get an output like this:

Sam became friends with ...

Or 

Sam likes ...

the dots being empty space.

Comment: Well, add `Reversed` field of date type and filter by it. If you show your SQL it will be easier to find solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my thoughts.

If users can delete something, you can record this also in your activity table.

I you want to hide that activity, you can add `ReversedOn` field and update it with the relevant date. Then you will just have to filter out activities that don't exist.

If that does not cause any user experience problems, then you can just let it be.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to take either of these approaches.

1. When the user deletes, just do the soft delete on the backend by marking them as deleted instead of hard deleting from the table.  You will have to introduce a new column "delete_flag" in this approach.
2. Archive the tables and move the records to a different table when deleted.  But this would be complex coding wise as well as the performance might not be as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply a couple of questions.

What difference would it make adding a delete flag to a row instead of just deleting the row itself as the row is no longer required.

Also What about for other things that the user doesn't have control over? I have activity for when users add news and profile pages to the site but I often remove news straight from phpmyadmin instead of through an admin section.

Comment: You will be able to use the foreign key constraints when you use the delete flag.  It should be handled on the business logic. whenever you fetch the activities for admin, you will have to apply a constraint that the delete_flag should be false.   This can be applied if you still want to preserve the data so that it will be used somewhere.  When you think this record and the other records that are referencing it is not required anymore, you can delete all those.